# .htaccess to redirect specific index file when url is visited

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

My product url looks like this: http://www.example.com/products/handbags/leather-handbag-model-ba123
where `handbags` is the category name and it is changing dynamically. 
`leather-handbag-model-ba123` is a product unique url and is also changing dynamically.
In the `.htaccess` file I have this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(products)/([^\s&]+)/([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule /%1/%2/index.php [L]
```

which is supposed to load index.php file which is located in /products/handbags/index.php, but the code returns error 404.
What will be the correct code that will load index.php file of the specific category (`handbags` in the example)?

Comment: Do you have a file "index.php" in "products/handbags" ?
If you don't... then that's why you get the 404.

You would need a lot of folders with "index.php" in them. That would be... 1 folder for every category...

Comment: yes, I have index.php in each category folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(products)/([^/]+)/.+/? /$1/$2/index.php [L]
```

Comment: You use THE_REQUEST to avoid loop with other RewriteRule ?

Comment: if I have this RewriteRule . ./products/Handbags/index.php [L]  redirect works but it is fixed to Handbags folder

Comment: But try [R=302,L,NE] with this one, to see the correct URL

Comment: after testing what you sugested I discover that this is wrong: RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(products)/([^\s&]+)/[^\s&]+ [NC]

Comment: And try with `RewriteRule ^$ /products/Handbags/index.php [L]` for other, if you try to redirect index. Why wrong ???

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67723/discussion-between-europeuser-and-croises).